# Check windows user exists with python

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to verify that user has access to the machine.

I'm trying to use [LogonUser](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32security__LogonUser_meth.html) as described [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/check-a-users-credentials.html):

```
    logging.info("checking credentials")
    try:
        win32security.LogonUser (
            name, 
            domain,
            password,
            win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
            win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
        )
    except win32security.error, e:
        logging.warn(e)
        raise e
    else:
        logging.info('pass')
```

However whatever I put as `name` or `password` (say `domain = None`) it always PASSES.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**: to reproduce:

```
import win32security

print win32security.LogonUser (
                "asdasdasdasdfagf", 
                None,
                "asdasdasdasdasda",
                win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
                win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
            )
```

output:

```
<PyHANDLE at 34009576 (276)>
```

Comment: Well, your edit certainly changes the question! Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't quite understand why -1. The question is not from Python 101. Obviously, I've tried to research before posting.

Comment: Because I answered the question that you originally asked when the code was utterly different. And now you edit to ask a completely different question. Using the code from my now deleted answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry I wasted your time by not being clear what "PASSES" is, I assumed that PASSES means no exception is raised, and I assumed that everybody would think so

Comment: But you changed the code. In the original version of the code, it always prints `pass` as I explained. Then you edit the question to have totally different code. Which came from my answer! And the code in the question, as it is now, will indeed report warnings when the name/pw combination is not valid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that's exactly the problem - it will NOT "*report warnings when the name/pw combination is not valid*"

Comment: Do you understand the change you made to the code? Do you understand how it totally alters the logic and flow of the program? Do you understand that your edit replicates my answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my concern (and question) is not about "*why would it print 'pass' at the end*", but "*why exception is never raise with any credentials*" Hence the question has a title "*Check windows user exists with python*"

Comment: The exception is raised. It was when I tried.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that's exactly my problem - in my case exception is not raised no matter what credentials I use.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. How do you diagnose that? What output of your program tells you that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, can we take it to the [chat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288447/check-windows-user-exists-with-python#)?

Comment: Not for me. Best would be to edit the Q so that we can reproduce. Include a complete program that we can run.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've updated with the code that it can be reproduced. P.S.: I do NOT have account "asdasdasdasdfagf" with password "asdasdasdasdasda" at the system

Comment: I get `pywintypes.error: (1326, 'LogonUser', 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.')`. So I can't repro. I can see how I got off on the wrong track here. Unfortunately your original post had an error that meant that the reporting was a bit off. But I understand that just masked the problem. I removed my downvote. I was huffy because I did find a real fault in your code and you then took my fix into your question. But I understand how it happened. Anyway, I've no idea how your machine could be behaving as you report.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks. I've now been able to reproduce my output on two machines. This is really strange.

Comment: Yeah, I can't work it out. Sorry. Good luck!

Comment: @bipen, and you've decided that this is "not a real question" because of ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I doubt it's actually the answer you are after, the only difference I can see between what you do to test, and the way I successfully in apps I use, is the use of the `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` flag instead of the `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` flag.  For what our products do though, we have specific requirements for the Desktop Interactivity, and I doubt it's actually a change that'll affect your results.

```
def testLogin(self):
  try:
    LogonUser(self.wrappers['User'].GetValue(),
              self.wrappers['Domain'].GetValue(),
              self.wrappers['Password'].GetRawValue(),
              LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
              LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
    RevertToSelf()
  except Exception, e:
    wx.MessageBox(unicode(e), _("Error"))
    return False
  return True
```

A domain value of `None` should look to the current domain, so if you're *really and truly* able to run this code with *any* username and password on your system, then either your system has problems, or your Domain has problems.

Comment: Great! Thanks! With `win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` It actually fails with wrong credentials and works with LOCAL and DOMAIN accounts!

Comment: I really don't get the root cause of the problem: maybe it's the domain is not configured properly (I created one along with AD DS for some tests) or the environment (my Admin has full Enterprise rights and it's Windows 2008 R2).